# How to run docker from inside a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, docker, jupyter, os.system

I have a jupyter notebook that is automating some data extraction, and I need to run that data past a parser living inside docker. My code is the following:

```
bnab_inp = "/data/bnab/"
bnab_out = '.fasta -o "/data/bnab/igblast"'

for item in bNAb:
    exe = str(activate_docker+bnab_inp+item+bnab_out)
    os.system(exe)
```

bNAb is  a dictionary that contains all the filenames to be parsed through igblast. I know the syntax of "exe" is correct, because if I copy and paste into a command prompt it runs with no fuss. However, using os.system produces no effects (and if I place it into a variable to get the *stdout* it returns 1).

I'm assuming that there is some limitation on how os.system runs that means I can't just paste the same command from the command prompt, but I can't seem to figure it out..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you should first put script with this code inside docker and later run it from outside.

Comment: @furas that's what I was dreading having to do, but it did indeed work, thanks !